# Accidentally overwrote dylib files to usr/local/lib by copying lib from application bundle

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, dylib, mp4box

I overwrote some of my dylib files in /usr/local/bin/ and now I'm having issues running a program. Is there a way of restoring these files back?

The program ffmpeg was running fine for me. Then I installed the program GPAC and did the following:

```
$ sudo cp MP4Box /usr/local/bin/

$ sudo cp -R /Applications/GPAC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
```

I did this because it would allow me to run MP4Box from the command line since /usr/local/lib/ is in $PATH.

But now when I try running

```
$ ffmpeg
```

I get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/sdl2/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib 
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg   Reason: Incompatible library
>   version: ffmpeg requires version 10.0.0 or later, but
>   libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib provides version 5.0.0 Abort trap: 6

I think what happened is: I overwrote some files into /usr/local/lib/ that I shouldn't have done. In this case, I overwrote the version 10.0.0 libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib with version 5.0.0 from the GPAC app bundle.

I have tried using homebrew to uninstall and reinstall ffmpeg, hoping that it would see that it would need to update my dylib libraries.

```
$ brew uninstall ffmpeg

$ brew install ffmpeg

$ ffmpeg
```

But this results in the same error.

Here is the list of all the files I copied from /Applications/GPAC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/* to /usr/local/lib/

libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib   libfreetype.6.dylib   libplds4.dylib
liba52.0.dylib        libgpac.dylib         libpng16.16.dylib
libavcodec.58.dylib   libjpeg.9.dylib       libpostproc.55.dylib
libavdevice.58.dylib  liblzma.5.dylib       libssl.1.0.0.dylib
libavfilter.7.dylib   libmad.0.dylib        libswresample.3.dylib
libavformat.58.dylib  libmozjs185.1.0.dylib libswscale.5.dylib
libavresample.4.dylib libmp3lame.0.dylib    libtheora.0.dylib
libavutil.56.dylib    libnspr4.dylib        libvorbis.0.dylib
libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libogg.0.dylib        libx264.152.dylib
libfaad.2.dylib       libplc4.dylib

Answer (score 2):

While running brew to reinstall ffmpeg directly did not work, I found out that running brew to reinstall ffmpeg's dependencies did work.

So for the earlier example, libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib wasn't loading correctly. I googled brew libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib, and found out that the brew package name for this was sdl2.

I ran

```
$ brew reinstall sdl2

$ ffmpeg
```

and I didn't get the libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib error anymore! I repeated this for each low level library that ffmpeg said it needed, and it eventually worked.